# How do I get the Parameter that is causing the sql to fail?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Right now I'm getting the following:

```
The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

While I can go through and null each parameter to find the issue, this will take hours once the whole sub routine is written. Is there a way to get which parameter is causing the issue?

p.s. This is the line causing the issue. It's simple to fix having found it. It just took a while to find.

```
SqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITIME", SqlDbType.Date).Value = IIf(IsNothing(ITIME), DBNull.Value, ITIME)
```

Comment: ummm is there a question or just an answer to something?

Comment: "this will take hours" - Unless you have a zillion parameters, I'm pretty sure stepping through the code would take nothing more than a few minutes.  Unless you're doing something really convoluted.....

Comment: Stepping through the code doesn't help. The parameters look fine until execution. What takes a while is making each one DBNull.Value until the SQL Command works. The error code is vague. So I'm looking for something most specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is when the exception is thrown, set a break point on the closing bracket of the catch block. Re-run the program and when the exception is thrown you can hover over and expand your command object. From there expand Parameters and in the right pane of the results view click the little icon to enumerate the results view. This will then allow you to expand the Results View in the left pane. Inside there you will see your parameters where you can check what values each holds at the time of the exception.

OK, hopefully this shows what I'm talking about. I ran short of screen real estate due to the expansions but you can do this through the locals window when the break point hits.

[image]

This is on VS2012. I will set this up in 2010 and see if it's different.

Comment: All I get is "Item = Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' accepts this number of arguments." I'm using VS2010, does this work in VS2015?

Comment: @Kayot, OK in 2010 it's different. I found them by expanding cmd (my command object) then Parameters then Non-public members then innerlist.

Comment: I went a head and just installed VS2015. I'm enjoying a few new features like multi-line text and of course the ability to see values parameters sent to the SQL command. Thanks for the answer.